# Is it possible to connect sas with Mysql without using sas/access facility

Tags: mysql, sas

I am using SAS 9.0. Is it possible for me to connect SAS with MySQL or excel?
Is it necessary to use SAS/Access to connect SAS to Excel or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS/ACCESS is the only way to connect to MySQL directly.  You might be able to use system commands to issue batch commands to write MySQL tables to text files, but  I suspect that's more work than just doing the exports by hand.

Excel can be connected to using DDE without SAS/ACCESS, though it's not a particularly efficient way to do significant transfers of data - again, you might save time exporting it by hand to CSV (or, using DDE to export it programmatically to CSV).

Comment: Hello Joe, Thanks for your response. Is it possible to have SAS/Access with SAS 9.0? Is any free version of SAS/ACCESS available?

Comment: You should talk to your SAS site rep or your local SAS admnin.  I also don't know how you manage to have SAS 9.0; that wasn't really a very long lasting release, and you should definitely upgrade as soon as you can (again, talk to the SAS site rep or your admin).